# How can I update my UI after a coroutine is completed in Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I use Retrofit and Coroutines to fetch a list of languages from an API. My ViewModel loads the list of languages whenever it is created. I want to load this list into a spinner, but whenever I update the spinner data, the data in the ViewModel hasn't completely loaded.

Here my viewmodel class to load data from an api

```
class TranslateViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var langToCode = HashMap<String, String>()
    var codeToLang = HashMap<String, String>()
    private val translateRepository = TranslateRepository()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val langList = try {
                translateRepository.getLangList()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e)
                return@launch
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "HTTPException", e)
                return@launch
            }
            if (langList.isSuccessful && langList.body() != null) {
                codeToLang = langList.body()!!.langList
                langToCode = codeToLang.map { (key, value) ->
                    value to key
                }.toMap() as HashMap<String, String>
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Get lang list failure")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load my list of languages into my spinner but my viewmodel is taking too long to load the data, so the langList variable is alway empty.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewBinding.apply {
            sourceLanguage.apply {
                val langList = viewModel.langToCode.keys.toList()
                val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter (
                    context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    langList
                ).also { it.setDropDownViewResource(
                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                )
                }
                this.adapter = arrayAdapter
        }
}
```

I want to know how to update my UI immediately after my coroutine has finished loading data. I appreciate all of your help, and please forgive me for my poor English skills.

Comment: Use observer to get data from viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your case update your viewmodel as below-

```
class TranslateViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _langList = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val langList: LiveData<List<String>> get() = _langList
    
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (langList.isSuccessful && langList.body() != null) {
                codeToLang = langList.body()!!.langList
                langToCode = codeToLang.map { (key, value) ->
                    value to key
                }.toMap() as HashMap<String, String>
                _langList.value = langToCode.keys.toList() // Update the LiveData value
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Get lang list failure")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your UI code to observe the LiveData and update the spinner as below-

```
viewModel.langList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { langList ->
            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
                context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                langList
            ).also { it.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
            )
            }
            sourceLanguage.adapter = arrayAdapter
        })
```

Follow this link for more detail - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata